# Como conectarme a 2 servidores de bd con node y MSSQL

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, nodos, mssql

Estimados tengo 2 bases de datos en servidores distintos , hasta el momento eh logrado conectarme a 1 servidor.

El problema esta cuando trato conectarme a las 2 bases de datos de manera simultanea , tengo el siguiente código, pero me eh dado cuanta que por mas que quiera conectarme a la Base de datos 2 , la cadena de conexion se mantiene con la primera conexion a la Base de datos 1.

**connection.js**

```
var  sql =require("mssql")
const config =require ('../config');

//BASE 1 
const dbSettings = { 
    user : config.dbUser,
    password : config.dbPassword,
    server : config.dbServer,
    port: config.dbPort,
    database : config.dbDatabase,
  
options: {
    encrypt: false,
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    parseJSON :true,
    }
};

// BASE 2
const dbSettingscax = {
    userc : config.dbUser,
    passwordc : config.dbPassword,
    serverc : config.dbCaxServer,
    portc: config.dbPort,
    databasec : config.dbCaxDatabase,
  
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        parseJSON :true,
        }
};
    //BASE 1 

 async function getConnection(){
    try {
        
            const pool = await sql.connect(dbSettings)
            return pool

} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    console.stack("---TRACE---")
}
}

//BASE 2 
async function getConnectioncax(){
    try {
        const pool = await sql.connect(dbSettingscax)
        return pool
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        console.stack("---TRACE---")
    }
}

module.exports = {

    getConnection : getConnection,
    sql,
   getConnectioncax:getConnectioncax


}
```

Eh leido que se tiene que administrar los grupos de conexiones, debido que la función .connect() de mssql es global entonces :

1. Dado que la base de datos A ya está conectada en el grupo global, la
   Solicitud 2 toma la conexión de la base de datos A

Como puedo administrar los grupos de conexiones o como puedo utilizar las múltiples conexiones alguna idea o sugerencia, se lo agradecería bastante.

Comment: Esta en la documentación oficial: https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#advanced-pool-management

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación , logre conectarme a 2 servidores de bases de datos (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fin logre conectarme a 2 servidores de sql server  mediante mssql.

Seguí las guías oficiales y esta guía el cual me sirvió bastante.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64254145/node-js-mssql-multiple-concurrent-connections-to-sql-servers-interfering-with-ea

Se tiene que crear un archivo de pool-manager.js y agregar el codigo siguiente.

```
    const { ConnectionPool } = require('mssql')
const pools = {}
 
// create a new connection pool
function CreatePool(config) {
    let key = JSON.stringify(config)

    if (GetPool(key))
        throw new Error('Pool already exists')

    pools[key] = (new ConnectionPool(config)).connect()
    return pools[key]
}

// get a connection pool from all pools
function GetPool(name) {
  if (pools[name])
    return pools[name]
  else
    return null
}

// if pool already exists, return it, otherwise create it
function GetCreateIfNotExistPool(config)  {
    let key = JSON.stringify(config)

    let pool = GetPool(key)
    if(pool)
        return pool
    else
    console.log(config)
        return CreatePool(config)
}

// close a single pool
function ClosePool(config) {
    let key = JSON.stringify(config)

    if (pools[key]) {
        const pool = pools[key];
        delete pools[key];
        pool.close()
        return true
    }
    return false
}

// close all the pools
function CloseAllPools() {
    pools.forEach((pool) => {
        pool.close()
    })
    pools = {}
    return true
}
 
module.exports = {
  ClosePool,
  CloseAllPools,
  CreatePool,
  GetPool,
  GetCreateIfNotExistPool
}
```

Luego en la clase de connection.js

agregue el codigo de la siguiente manera.

```
    var  sql =require("mssql")
const config =require ('../config');
const poolManager = require('./pool-manager')
//BASE 1 
const dbSettings = { 
    user : config.dbUser,
    password : config.dbPassword,
    server : config.dbServer,
    port: config.dbPort,
    database : config.dbDatabase,
  
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        parseJSON :true,
        }
};
// BASE 2
const dbSettingscax = {
    user : config.dbUser,
    password : config.dbPassword,
    server: config.dbCaxServer,
    port: config.dbPort,
    database : config.dbCaxDatabase,
  
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        parseJSON :true,
        }
};
//BASE 1 
 async function getConnection(){
    try {
                    const pool = await poolManager.GetCreateIfNotExistPool(dbSettings)
                    //await pool.connect()
                     return pool 
    
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        console.stack("---TRACE---")
    }
}

//BASE 2 

async function getConnectioncax(){
    try {
        const pool2 =await poolManager.GetCreateIfNotExistPool(dbSettingscax)
       return pool2
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        console.stack("---TRACE---")
    }
}
module.exports = {
    getConnection : getConnection,
    sql,
   getConnectioncax:getConnectioncax
}
```